# Get an additional column from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query below that I use on a supermarket database to see the Items available for online sale SAP DB using SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT T0.[CodeBars], T0.[ItemName], T3.[Price], T1.[Price], T2.[ItmsGrpNam]
FROM OITM T0 INNER JOIN ITM1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITB T2 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T2.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T3 ON T0.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode 
WHERE T0.[U_Online] = 'Y' AND T1.[PriceList] = '3' AND T3.[Pricelist]='1'
```

The query works fine but I want to add another column for OnHand items. I.e. Items that are in stock for a particular warehouse '6' where all items for online sale come from. The supermarket has 8 warehouses. The `T0.[U_Online] = 'Y'` shows items sold online regardless of warehouse.

How do I modify the query below such that for every `T0.[CodeBars]` returned, I get an additional column for Onhand items for warehouse 6? I have an extra join for table OITW.

```
SELECT T0.[CodeBars], T0.[ItemName], T3.[Price], T1.[Price], T2.[ItmsGrpNam],
T4.OnHand
FROM OITM T0 INNER JOIN ITM1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITB T2 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T2.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T3 ON T0.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITW T4 ON T0.ItemCode = T4.ItemCode
WHERE T0.[U_Online] = 'Y' AND T1.[PriceList] = '3' AND T3.[Pricelist]='1'
--AND T4.WhsCode = '6'
```

Sample results from 1st query

Comment: With the AND T4.WhsCode = '6', the query returns no results, the top one 877 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need `LEFT JOIN` instead, like this:

```
SELECT 
  T0.[CodeBars], 
  T0.[ItemName], 
  COALESCE(T3.[Price], T1.[Price]) AS Price, 
  T2.[ItmsGrpNam],
  T4.OnHand
FROM       OITM T0 
LEFT JOIN ITM1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode   = T1.ItemCode   AND T1.[PriceList] = '3'
LEFT JOIN OITB T2 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T2.ItmsGrpCod 
LEFT JOIN ITM1 T3 ON T0.ItemCode   = T3.ItemCode   AND T3.[Pricelist] = '1'
LEFT JOIN OITW T4 ON T0.ItemCode   = T4.ItemCode   AND T4.WhsCode = '6'
WHERE T0.[U_Online] = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mahmoud Gamal. Your query seems fine other than all the OnHand item results are null.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau It might be there is no items have `WhsCode = '6'`. Can you please update your question with some sample data of these three tables `OITM`, `ITM1`, `OITB` and `OITW` and the expected result. IT will be very helpful.

Comment: I found out what was the problem. Thanks.